# Loading Megatron NLP Pretrained Model and Training it with my own data. Errors

Tags: nlp, transformer-model, pytorch-lightning, large-language-model

I am getting errors.  My most recent one being:  ImportError: cannot import name 'LightningDistributedModule' from 'pytorch_lightning.overrides'.

I'm trying to load a pre-trained model and then teach it with other files.  I have the links to these file locations in the Sharefiles.txt and I'm looking for the code to go one line at a time, load the link, open the file, train the model and then loop back to the next line in the file locations document.

This is what I have so far for my code:

```
import nemo
import mimetypes
import torch
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pathlib import Path
from nemo.collections.nlp.modules.language_model import MegatronForSequenceClassification
from nemo.core.classes.module import LightningDistributedModule

# Create a Megatron model
model =  nemo.collections.nlp.modules.language_model.MegatronForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('megatron-bert-345m-uncased')


# Load the pretrained Megatron model
model.load_pretrained('megatron-bert-345m-uncased')

# Read the list of links from a text file
with open('ShareFiles.txt', 'r') as f:
    links = f.readlines()

# Go through each link in the list
for link in links:
    # Remove the newline character from the end of the link
    link = link.strip()

    # Get the content type of the file
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(link)[0]

    # Open the file
    with open(link, 'r') as f:
        # Train the model on the file
        model.train(f, content_type=content_type)

# Save the model
model.save_pretrained('my_megatron_model')
```